# I get a problem in Android RecyclerView getAdapterPosition()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I get a problem in Android RecyclerView `holder.getAdapterPosition()`. I take the position access using

```
 int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

Here I have used this condition to make clickable the O position item.

```
int p = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (p == 0){
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    String id = dataReturn.getFromNumber();
                    // Handle the item click here
                    // Move the clicked item to the top of the list
                    Toast.makeText(context,  id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /* Intent theIntent = new Intent(context, UserAllDataShow.class);
                    theIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(theIntent);*/
                }
            });

        }
```

But here I am get a problem. I want to make clickable item 0 but make also the clickable position 7. If I click the 7th position item that works but I want to make clickable the position 0.
Why this problem? how can I solve this?

My adapter class in below

```
package com.leaveapplication.mosw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DataReturn> list;

    public ReportAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataReturn> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.report_user, parent, false);
        return new ReportAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);
        holder.reportId.setText(dataReturn.getFromNumber());
        holder.reportName.setText(dataReturn.getName());
        holder.reportRank.setText(dataReturn.getRank());
        holder.reportLastVacation.setText(dataReturn.getLastVacation());
        holder.reportNextVacation.setText(dataReturn.getComingEnd());
        String image = dataReturn.getImage();
        if (image.equals("")){
            holder.circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
        }else {
            Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.circleImageView);
        }
        int p = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (p == 0){
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    String id = dataReturn.getFromNumber();
                    // Handle the item click here
                    // Move the clicked item to the top of the list
                    Toast.makeText(context,  id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /* Intent theIntent = new Intent(context, UserAllDataShow.class);
                    theIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(theIntent);*/
                }
            });

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CircleImageView circleImageView;
        TextView reportName, reportLastVacation, reportNextVacation, reportRank,reportId;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            reportId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            reportName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_name);
            reportLastVacation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_last_vacation);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_profile_image);
            reportRank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_rank);
            reportNextVacation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.next_vacation);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try moving the condition check `if (p == 0) { ... }` inside the `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener`. I bet the issue you are facing is due to some view recycling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem using this.

I thing this is a bug in recyclerViewr's `holder.getAdapterPosition()`  method.
The solved code is below. Thank you for try to help me.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.getLayoutPosition() == 0){
                    DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(0);
                    String id = dataReturn.getFromNumber();
                    // Handle the item click here
                    // Move the clicked item to the top of the list
                    Toast.makeText(context,  id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /* Intent theIntent = new Intent(context, UserAllDataShow.class);
                    theIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(theIntent);*/
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

onBindViewHolder already providing the list position. you can check this "position" to make your 0 position item clickable like this ::

```
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (holder.getAdapterPosition.getAbsoluteValue==0){ 
                        DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);
                        String id = dataReturn.getFromNumber();
                        // Handle the item click here
                        // Move the clicked item to the top of the list
                        Toast.makeText(context,  id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       /* Intent theIntent = new Intent(context, UserAllDataShow.class);
                        theIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                        
                  
        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(theIntent);*/
                    }
                  }
                });
```

Comment: onBindViewHolder position is not accessible.  I tried.  ```DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);``` this position is fixed. We can get access to this data. When I tried this code that you give the same problem is happening.

Comment: I think the problem is on recyclerView. You can try this .it worked::

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.adapterPosition.absoluteValue==0){
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, holder.adapterPosition.absoluteValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
            });

Comment: Check the position after the click

Comment: brother there is not any method without ```()```  in java and recyclerView don't have that type of method.

Answer (score 0):

if onBindViewHolder position is not accessible then you can do this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position){
int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

   //If you want to get a particular 0 position click event, then you need to declare like this: 

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                if (pos == 0){ 
                    DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);
                    String id = dataReturn.getFromNumber();
                    System.out.printl(dataReturn);
                } else if(pos == 1){
                  // Do something for position 1
                } else{
                  //Do something for others
                }
              }
            });
}
```

Comment: onBindViewHolder position is not accessible. I told it before you can try.